# Bootstrap Carousel Image jumping

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having issue with Twbs 3.1 Carousel , I set image to margin-left and right auto to be always in the middle. When Carousel slider on bigger screen res >1400px  image is jumping from left to center.

I need to fix it , can somebody please help me ?

Some code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1400X500">
        <div class="container">

            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1400X500">
        <div class="container">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1400X500">
        <div class="container">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1400X500">
        <div class="container">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1400X500">
        <div class="container">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
</a>
```

.css

```
.item.active img{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

}

And link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3041/
Best Regards

Comment: Your fiddle looks fine on my computer. I have a resolution of 1600x900. Am just taking a guess where your code could go wrong, it jumps probably because the `.active` class is only added after the slide transition is done, hence your `margin` properties will not take effect until then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the css of your

```
.item.active img{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

to

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img{
    margin:auto;
}
```

#### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3048/)

#### [Fiddle Full Screen](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3048/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 3):

Call this class:

```
.carousel-inner .item,
.carousel-inner .item.active,
.carousel-inner .item img {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Thanks Antonio(anu2x)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to remove .carousel-inner { padding: 5px; }. It was jumping because the padding was applied.